# Proposition of fast algorithm for graph with weights

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, recursive-algorithms, planar-graphs

If ever your Djkstra algorithms are in a situation where the max weight is much smaller than the number of vertices in your graph, try transforming each weight of size "x" into "x" new edges connected by new vertices and this will turn your Problem from the most short weighted paths into a weightless problem which will be solved in complexity O ("max weight" x "number of vertices") which is asymptotically better and faster than the basic problem.
Tell me if you find something wrong.

Thank you

Comment: If weights are decimal, do you scale all the weights by factors of 10 until all of them are integers? How does one work with negative weights?

Comment: It does not work in negative weights such as Djikstra, but if weights are decimals you scale them as you said, but it can make the weights really big, so as I said , this algorithm would work in some cases.

Comment: [The Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Specialized_variants) describes some similarly fast variants in the case of small integer weights.